# Jersey interceptor и filter

Tags: java, filter, jersey

Использую Jersey версии 2.13 и у меня есть куча методов такого вида:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/getstate/{unitId}")
public DashboardPanelStatus getstate(@PathParam ("unitId") Long unitId) 
                                                     throws JsonProcessingException{
    return dashboardService.getSmartPanelStatus(null, unitId, true);
}
```

где фигурирует `unitId`. Мне нужно написать что-то вроде фильтра или interceptor, который будет как аннотация вешаться на REST-методы и проверять, доступен ли тот или иной `unitId`. Если он доступен, то идем дальше, если нет —  кидаем `403`.

Использовать `ContainerRequestFilter` не получилось, так как там есть только `URL`, а мне нужен именно мой параметр. `ReaderInterceptor` не реагирует на GET-запросы.

[Пробовал по официальной документации Jersey Name binding](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@PanelSecurity
@Provider
public class PanelSecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter  {

@Context UriInfo uriInfo;

@Context private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    HttpSession session = servletRequest.getSession();
    String unitId = uriInfo.getPathParameters().get("unitId").get(0);


}
```

Инжектим в фильтр UriInfo, в нем есть все @PathParam-ы